# How do I force Spring Boot to read the DB connection configuration from application.properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, configuration

Basic configurations are written in **hibernate.cfg.xml**. There was a need to transfer the password, username and database name in **application.properties**. However, I can't tell the system to read this data from application.properties. I tried to use the `@PropertySources` annotation and write the required file in `.configure ()` during initializing the SessionFactory. How do I tell Spring to read the password, user, and database name from application.properties?

Service.java:

```
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("application.properties") }) // doesn't work
@Service
public class Service {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml") // replaced hibernate.cfg.xml for application.properties   
            .addAnnotatedClass(FileEntity.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();

---methods---

}
```

Part of hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="com.group.appName.model.FileEntity" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=9090
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
```

ApplicationContextConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.group.appName")
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(Service.class);
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(FileEntity.class);
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager" )
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver getCommonsMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520); // 20MB
        multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);  // 1MB
        return multipartResolver;
  
}
```

Comment: You have not need to configure hibernate manually. Spring Data already provides a JPA implementation (hibernate). If you add Spring Data as dependency you can specify all the configuration values in application.properties

Comment: I'm confused. You actually define a bean for `sessionFactory` in your config. And then, instead of `@Autowire`-ing that bean, you create another `sessionFactory` from scratch in your `@Service` class. Just use `@Autowire private SessionFactory sessionFactory` instead and everything will start working

Comment: @crizzis, absolutely right. But! When I try to delete 
`private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")  
            .addAnnotatedClass(FileEntity.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();`
and try to use autowired sessionFactory app doesn't compile.
I get error `Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver`

Comment: @vincendep, and I thought so. But if I delete `.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")` app doesn't compile :-(